# How to store simultaneous keypresses

Tags: javascript, keyup

When I use the key-up event listener in JavaScript, the keys "wait" before starting again. I think it's because the key-up needs to listen to specific keys but for me that hasn't worked yet.

I have tried using different tutorials for different perspectives on this problem, but none of them have worked for me yet... I think I just need to not use the key-up event listener but I'm not sure how. I only have only known JavaScript for a few weeks so I don't know how to use advanced methods for things.

```js
var key = "";
document.addEventListener('keyup', e => { key = ""; });
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => { key = e.code; });
setInterval(e => {
    document.getElementById('test').innerText = key;
}, Infinity);
```

```html
<p>Press and hold keys...</p>
<p id="test"></p>
```

If you were to press A, then press D right afterward, it would wait a bit before saying D is pressed. That is a problem because I'm trying to be able to make a gamepad for pressing multiple keys at once.

Comment: *'the keys "wait" before starting again'*: please clarify what that means. What does it mean for a key to "wait" or to "start"? What is your code snippet supposed to illustrate?

Comment: If you were to press A, then press D right afterward, it would wait a bit before saying D is pressed.

Comment: But the code you have provided does not illustrate that. Can you provide code that illustrates the problem when pressing A and D in short sequence?

Comment: Could the delay have to do with waiting for the key to come *up* (that is, be *released*), instead of processing it when it is initially pressed *down*? Typical  ui actions respond to `keydown` events, not `keyup`.

Comment: That is what I initially said

Comment: I adjusted the code of your question to clearly demonstrate the problem in a runnable snippet.  Note that holding a key down allows you to press another key down while holding the first, but when releasing the first, you will still get repeated keydown messages for the key still being held down due to the way key repeat works.  This is as expected, but I think this may be what you are describing as "the keys "wait"

Comment: What is the point of calling `setInterval` with an interval value of infinity? The second argument to `setInterval` is the *time between the callback firings*...why even use the global var instead of just updating the DOM in the event listeners? None of this makes any sense...

Comment: setting Infinity as an interval is basically an alternatve of setting it to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Set` ([mdn reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)) to track all keys currently pressed. Your current approach of using a single string, `key`, is impractical for storing multiple keys.

```js
const codes = new Set();

const updateDisplay = (mode, evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (mode === 'add') codes.add(evt.code);
  if (mode === 'rem') codes.delete(evt.code);
  document.querySelector('.state').textContent = [ ...codes ].join(' + ') || '(no keys)';
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', evt => updateDisplay('add', evt));
window.addEventListener('keyup', evt => updateDisplay('rem', evt));

window.addEventListener('focus', () => document.querySelector('.focus').style.display = 'none');
window.addEventListener('blur', () => document.querySelector('.focus').style.display = '');
```

```html
<div class="focus">WINDOW IS UNFOCUSED; CANNOT PROCESS KEY EVENTS (please click)</div>
<p>Press and release buttons (potentially many at once)</p>
<p>Current state: <span class="state">(no keys)</span></p>
```

Comment: Is a set like an array?

Comment: @Nickgaming it's similar, but it automatically prevents duplicate values, and it makes it convenient to delete an item by value (in an Array you may need to use an index instead). It usually makes sense to track keyboard inputs in a `Set`. I'll add a documentation link!